# Kivy Multiple questions on a tank game

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have some questions about this game I'm making...

First, When I press `F` which makes the tank fire, the `weapon_explosion.zip`'s images are all placed on top of each other and causes massive lag.

Second, After I fire lots of buggy things happen:
Firing again makes the bullet go the same direction again.
The bullet accelerates to extremely high speeds ?
(The explosion lags)

Third:
How do I make a `.zip` animation go once, I just went around it by destroying it after ~2.5 seconds

Now, here is my code:

`PlayerImage Class` (The tank):

```
class PlayerImage(Image):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.tuplePos = None
        self.y = 122
        self.eventf = None

        self.eventr = None
        self.source = './rpgArt/tankright.zip'
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.gravity(), 1.0 / 60.0)
        super(PlayerImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self, None)
        if not self._keyboard:
            return
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_key_down)
        self.gravVelocity = 1
        self.bullet = ""
        self.explosion = None

        self.iterationBul = 0
        self.left = None
        self.iterations = 0
        self.weapon = "./rpgArt/"
        self.redtank = "./rpgArt/tankModels/tank_red/"
        self.bluetank = "./rpgArt/tankModels/tank_red/"

        self.redtankRight = self.redtank + "normal/tank_red_right.zip"
        self.redtankLeft = self.redtank + "normal/tank_red_left.zip"

        self.bullet = Image(source=self.weapon + "weapon_bullet.zip")




    def on_key_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):

        if keycode[1] == "right" or keycode[1] == "d":
            self.source = self.redtankRight
            self.x += 5
        if keycode[1] == "left" or keycode[1] == "a":
            self.source = self.redtankLeft
            self.x -= 5
        if keycode[1] == "up" or keycode[1] == "spacebar" or keycode[1] == "w":
            if self.source == self.redtankLeft:
                self.source = self.redtankLeft
            if self.source == self.redtankRight:
                self.source = self.redtankRight
            self.y += 50

        if keycode[1] == "f":
            if self.source == self.redtankLeft:
                self.bullet = Image(source=self.weapon + "weapon_bullet.zip")
                self.source = self.redtank + "fire/tank_red_left_fire.zip"
                self.tuplePos = self.x - 50, self.y - 3
                self.bullet.pos = self.tuplePos  # TODO POSITION BULLET
                self.add_widget(self.bullet)
                if self.bullet is not None:
                    self.eventr = Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.moveBullet(), 1.0 / 60.0)  # TODO MOVE BULLET CLOCK
            elif self.source == self.redtankRight:
                self.bullet = Image(source=self.weapon + "weapon_bullet.zip")
                self.source = self.redtank + "fire/tank_red_right_fire.zip"
                self.tuplePos = self.x + 50, self.y - 3
                self.bullet.pos = self.tuplePos
                self.add_widget(self.bullet)
                if self.bullet is not None:
                    self.eventr = Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.moveBullet(), 1.0 / 60.0)

    def moveBullet(self):
        if self.iterationBul == 0:
            if self.source == self.redtank + "fire/tank_red_left_fire.zip":
                self.left = True
                self.iterationBul = 1
            elif self.source == self.redtank + "fire/tank_red_right_fire.zip":
                self.left = False
                self.iterationBul = 1
        else:
            if self.left is True:
                self.eventf = Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.movebulletleft(), 5.0 / 20.0)
            if self.left is False:
                self.eventf = Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.movebulletright(), 5.0 / 20.0)

    def movebulletleft(self):

        if self.bullet is None:
            self.bullet = Image(source=self.weapon + "weapon_bullet.zip")
        else:
            x, y = self.tuplePos
            if x < 0:
                self.explosion = Image(source=self.weapon + "weapon_explosion.zip")
                self.explosion.pos = x, y
                self.add_widget(self.explosion)
                self.remove_widget(self.bullet)
                Clock.unschedule(self.eventf)
                Clock.unschedule(self.eventr)
                self.iterationBul = 0
                self.left = None

                self.bullet = None
                Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.REexplosion(), 5)
            else:
                self.bullet.pos = (x - 3, y)
                self.tuplePos = self.bullet.pos
                print('left is true')
                print(str(self.bullet.pos) + " bullet pos")

    def REexplosion(self):
        self.remove_widget(self.explosion)

    def movebulletright(self):
        if self.bullet is None:
            self.bullet = Image(source=self.weapon + "weapon_bullet.zip")

        else:
            self.bullet.pos = (x, y) = self.tuplePos
            if x > 680:
                self.explosion = Image(source=self.weapon + "weapon_explosion.zip")
                self.explosion.pos = x, y
                self.add_widget(self.explosion)
                self.remove_widget(self.bullet)
                Clock.unschedule(self.eventf)
                Clock.unschedule(self.eventr)
                self.iterationBul = 0
                self.left = None

                self.bullet = None
                Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.REexplosion(), 1.7)
            else:
                v = 3
                self.bullet.pos = (x + v, y)
                self.tuplePos = self.bullet.pos
                print('right is true')
                try:
                    print(str(self.bullet.pos) + " bullet pos")
                except AttributeError:
                    print("bullet out of range!")



    def gravity(self):
        if self.y == 123:
            pass
        else:
            self.y -= 2
        if self.y <= 122:
            self.y += 1
        # if self.iterations / 60 != 0:
        #     result = self.iterations / 60
        #     self.gravVelocity += result
        # print(self.y)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        # self.currentstate = self.states["person.zip/"]
        Animation.cancel_all(self)
        angle = degrees(atan2(touch.y - self.center_y,
                              touch.x - self.center_x))

        Animation(center=touch.pos, angle=angle).start(self)
        # self.currentstate = self.states["personred/rest.png/"]
        print(self.y)
```

Also, my `Builder.load_string`s:

```
root = Builder.load_string('''
Widget:
    Widget:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 0,0,1
            Rectangle:
                size: (900,500)
                pos: (0,150)
    Widget:
        Image:
            pos: (0,150)
            size: (400,400)
            source: './rpgArt/city.zip'
    Widget:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 0,1,0
            Rectangle:
                size: (900,150)
                pos: (0,0)
        PlayerImage:
            source: './rpgArt/tankModels/tank_red/normal/tank_red_right.zip'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
            pos:(0,130)


''')


runTouchApp(root)
```

And the other one which I don't fully understand... (From someone else.)

```
Builder.load_string('''
<PlayerImage>:
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix

''')
```

Comment: Also, if anyone will actually answer this ( :( ) How can I add collision for the bullet/explosion hitting the tank?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to unschedule `self.eventr` at `movebullet(self):`.

`Clock.unschedule(self.eventr)`